# Custom intents are not triggered by voice commands

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to use Custom Intents in Android, but I can't trigger them through voice commands, only through the App Actions Test Tools. Does anyone know what voice command I need to give for it to be accepted? Below are the settings of my code.

I tried to debug the command sent by the App Actions Test Tools, but I was not successful.

https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/custom-intents

```
  <shortcut
    android:shortcutId="arm Central"
    android:shortcutShortLabel="@string/activity_arm_central">
    <capability-binding android:key="custom.actions.intent.ARM_CENTRAL">
        <parameter-binding
            android:key="apptType"
            android:value="@array/ExampleQueries" />
    </capability-binding>
</shortcut>

<capability
    android:name="custom.actions.intent.ARM_CENTRAL"
    app:queryPatterns="@array/ExampleQueries">
    <intent
        android:action="android.intent.action.VIEW"
        android:targetClass="com.devrel.android.fitactions.FitMainActivity"
        android:targetPackage="com.teste.app.actions.google">
        <url-template android:value="https://example.com/appt{apptType}" />
        <parameter android:name="apptType" android:key="apptType" />
    </intent>
</capability>
```

my arrays.xml

```
   <string-array name="ExampleQueries">
       <item>Activate central $apptType</item>
       <item>Armar central $apptType</item>
       <item>Arm central $apptType</item>
   </string-array>
```

My String.xml

```
    <string name="activity_arm_central">Arm Central</string>
```